# UITableView cells don't show labels and buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has its delegate and dataSource properties set correctly, however its content isn't showing.

**MY Code**

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    BOOL notInputNotes;
    UIColor *normalBlue = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:0.1 green:0.65 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
    HomeWork *hw = [hwArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *dateDueAsText = [dateFormat stringFromDate:hw.dateDue];
    CGFloat xForDate;
    if (dateDueAsText.length < 16 || dateDueAsText.length == 16) {
        xForDate = 215;
    }
    else{
        xForDate = 214;
    }
    hw.indexPath = indexPath;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (!isEditing) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell setEditing:NO];
    }
    else{
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
        [cell setEditing:YES];
    }
    UILabel *subject = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 5, 150, 45)];
    if(![hw.subject isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        subject.text = hw.subject;
        notInputNotes = NO;
    }
    else{
        subject.text = hw.notes;
        subject.frame = CGRectMake(70, 20, 150, 45);
        notInputNotes = YES;
    }
    [subject setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [subject setTextColor:normalBlue];
    subject.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    subject.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];//test
    [cell addSubview:subject];
    if(!notInputNotes){
        UILabel *notes = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 40, 300, 30)];
        notes.text = hw.notes;
        [notes setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        notes.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [notes setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [cell addSubview:notes];
    }
    UILabel *importancy = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 45, 200, 30)];
    importancy.text = hw.importancy;
    [importancy setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [importancy setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    importancy.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [cell addSubview:importancy];
    UILabel *dateDue = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xForDate, 10, 200, 30)];
    dateDue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateDueAsText];
    [dateDue setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    dateDue.textColor = normalBlue;
    dateDue.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [cell addSubview:dateDue];
    hw.doneButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, 40, 40)];
        if(!hw.done){
            [hw.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else{
            [hw.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    [hw.doneButton addTarget:hw action:@selector(done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = -1;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *nowMinus1 = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSComparisonResult result;
    result = [nowMinus1 compare:hw.dateDue];
    if(result==NSOrderedDescending && !(hw.done)){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.86 alpha:0.6];
        NSLog(@"%@ is earlier than %@",dateDueAsText,[dateFormat stringFromDate:nowMinus1]);
            [hw.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lighter-gray_unckecked.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        hw.late = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        hw.late = NO;
    }
    [cell addSubview:hw.doneButton];
    return cell;
}
```

Does somebody know what's wrong there? Thanks in advance.

**Note**
the cell's background color appears different if you set it, so the cells are there and re correctly made the problem is really with the views

Comment: why are you removing UIView from cell subview? Also you have specified cell style to be default and adding custom UILabel to it. If you need to create a custom cell you can do the same using storyboards.

Comment: @user2071152 I'm removing UIView form the subview because if I didn't the cells would overlap each other

Comment: Oh My God !. Never in my life I have overburdened `cellForRowAtIndex` method so much. Try adding `subviews` to `cell.contentView`. ALso, why dont you create a custom cell for this. COde will be lot readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is a really good practice to remove all subviews of a UITableViewCell and add your own subviews after. It would be better to subclass UITableViewCell.

That being said, you can try this instead, it will display your content.

```
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But your problem definitely comes from you wanting to remove the subviews. If the first problem is cell overlapping try implementing

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return customHeight;
}
```